# Optimization of Dijkstras

Tags: dijkstra

I would like some help to optimize this code. In the part where I
initialize all the ArrayLists, it feels insufficient that I have to set
them to default values for the size of the path ArrayList, since I am only 
interested for the path from the source node to the destination node. Do you
guys have any idea on how to fix this?

Cheers!

```
//Shortest path algorithm
public void shortestPath(String source, String end){    

    /*
     * Init the vertices, init the distances
     * Set the distance from the start node to itself to 0
     */
    copy = g.getMap();  

    initArrays(copy);

    holdCost.add(agent.get(source), 0);
    pq.insert(new Vertex(source, 0));

    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        Vertex v = pq.getRoot();
        pq.delete(pq.getRoot());

        visited.set(agent.get(v), true);    
        for(Edge e : copy.get(v)){
            if(!visited.get(agent.get(e))){
                if(holdCost.get(agent.get(e)) > (holdCost.get(agent.get(v))    
                 + e.getWeight())){
                    holdCost.set(agent.get(e), (holdCost.get(agent.get(v)) 
                                                        + e.getWeight()));
                    pq.insert(new Vertex(path.get(agent.get(e)),
                                   holdCost.get(agent.get(e))));
                    cost.add(holdCost.get(agent.get(e)));
                }if(visited.get(agent.get(end))){
                    break;
                }
            }               
        }               
    }
}

//Initiliaze of distance, nodes etc
public void initArrays(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>> h){
    for(String s : h.keySet()){
        path.add(s);
        holdCost.add(path.indexOf(s), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        visited.add(path.indexOf(s), false);
        agent.put(s, path.indexOf(s)); //easy to get the same index as  vertices, distances etc
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add declarations and meaning of your class variables? I mean path, for example.

Comment: And how do you actually retrieve the path from source to end? You said you are interested in this path and want to optimize the algorithm but there is the missing part of it.

Comment: #1
    private PriorityQueue<Vertex> pq;  
    private Graph g;
    private ArrayList<String> path;
    private ArrayList<String> s2d;private ArrayList<Boolean> visited;
private ArrayList<Integer> holdCost;
private ArrayList<Integer> cost;
private HashMap<String, Integer> agent = new HashMap<>();
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>> copy; )

#2
I have a made a Graph that takes veritices and edges. The vertices are strings!

Comment: I still can't see the part where you get the actual shortest path from source to end. Usually a value for predecessor is stored for each node and updated when you find shorter path to some vertex. Than you can go back from the end to source using predecessors

The important thing is you have a bug in your code. You initialize hold costs for max value of int and then you add something to it. Remember that this addition is by default performed on integers unless e.getWeight() returns long. This way you get integer overflow and a negative result here `holdCost.get(agent.get(v)) + e.getWeight())`.

Comment: Alllright, thank you! I am new to this site, so I have had som problem with pasting up code in the comment section, sry!